# Parse custom datetime format, and convert to UTC

Tags: python

I have a string containing datetime like `"2016-12-01T23:59:29-05:00"`, `"2018-2-1T13:50:29-04:00"`.
I want to convert this from this format (containing time difference of `-5:00` / `-4:00`) to UTC timezone. I tried searching for some documentation online on how to approach this, but can't seem to find anything useful.

So far I have the following code, but it fails on `ValueError: unconverted data remains: -05:00`

```
raw_dt = "2016-12-01T23:59:29-05:00"
parsed_dt = datetime.strptime(raw_dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
utc_dt = parsed_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(utc_dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I posted this question, I came across the parser tool. So, I'm able to parse the date via:

```
import pytz
from dateutil.parser import parse

cust_dt = parse('2016-12-01T23:59:29-05:00')
utc_dt = cust_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)


print(utc_dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parsed_dt = datetime.strptime(raw_dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Adding a `%z` to time format string instructs strptime to keep the timezone.